# PHP loop make variable available in the next loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop like this (just a sample, many vars are missing):

```
foreach($inserts as $insert) {

$insert_update = 'INSERT INTO etc.. SET etc..'; // returns the last inserted ID

$insertedIDs[] = array($tables[$tbl]['owner'] => $insert_update);
}
```

Now as you see `$insertedIDs[]` is getting in the array all the new inserted IDs.
The problem is that on the next `$inserts` loop I'll need that `$insertedIDs[]` to be available for other variables of the loop, that will need to get the last inserted ID.
The problem is that on the next loop this variable is not recognized and it returns errors.

How can I make `$insertedIDs[]` available on each next loop after the first loop?

I tried declaring `$insertedIDs[]` as global just after the `foreach` but no luck.

Comment: Surely it should be declared just before the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it'll help you:

```
$insertedIDs=Array();
foreach($inserts as $insert) {

$insert_update = 'INSERT INTO etc.. SET etc..'; // returns the last inserted ID

$insertedIDs[] = array($tables[$tbl]['owner'] => $insert_update);
}
```

Now you are able to access $insertedIDs

Answer (score 0):

```
$insertedIDs = array();

foreach($inserts as $insert) {
    $insert_update = 'INSERT INTO etc.. SET etc..'; // returns the last inserted ID
    $insertedIDs[ $tables[$tbl]['owner'] ] = $insert_update;
}

print_r($insertedIDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy actually... Try not to over-think it.

```
//create an empty array
var $insertedIds = array();

//now loop and add to the array
foreach( $inserts as $insert )
{
    $insert_update = 'INSERT INTO etc.. SET etc..'; // returns the last inserted ID
    $insertedIds[][$tables[$tbl]['owner']] = $insert_update;

    //or if you want the owners to be keys in the first level of the array...
    //$insertedIds[$tables[$tbl]['owner']] = $insert_update;
}

//output the contents of the array
echo '<pre>' . print_r($insertedIds, true) . '</pre>';
```